# For a general ring $R$, if $R$ has a unique right-unity, then it has a unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Problem:** For a general ring $R$ I want to show that:
if $R$ has a unique right unity, then it has an overall unity.

**Attempt:**
Suppose $e$ is the unique right unity of $R$. Then for any $r \in R$, we have that
$re=r$ and so $er=ere$ and $er-ere=0$. From here I feel the answer should be obvious but I'm not seeing it right away. Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $R$ has an identity or $R$ has a unit?

Comment: @JohnDouma unity=identity I believe.

Comment: I have never seen that term.

Comment: @JohnDouma ok. well I got it from Nicholson's Abstract Algebra.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't exist. I just have never heard of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that it is unique. Suppose there is no element $s$ such that $sr=rs=r$ for all $r$. Then there exists $r$ such that $er\neq r$. Then $e'=e+er-r$ is a distinct right identity, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This seems correct to me. Just having difficulty seeing why $e'$ is an identity.

Comment: @Integrate It's a proof by contradiction. It shows that a two sided identity must exist. Since this would also be a right identity, it is in fact equal to $e$. It's not required to show that though.

Comment: Nevermind. All good thanks!

Comment: @Integrate That wouldn't be true necessarily. $e'$ is a fabricated element that doesn't exist. You could phrase it as a direct proof by saying that if the ring has a right identity that is not a left identity, then the right identity is not unique. There's no mention of a left identity there.

Comment: @Integrate Sure, no problem.